# Spring mongodb projection on repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I Try to use this feature:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

So I have one class:

```
@Document
public class Ficha {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Parte parte;
    private String observacao;
    private Integer numero;
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime cadastro;
    private String livro;
    private String folha;
    private String papelSeguranca;
    private String selo;
    private Usuario atendente;
    private Escrevente escrevente;
    private Biometria digital;
    private List<Imagem> documentos;
}
```

Then I create one interface to return only 2 fields:

```
public interface FichaSemParte {
    Integer getNumero();
    String getLivro();
}
```

And in my repository I put:

```
public interface FichaRepository extends CrudRepository<Ficha, String> {

    FichaSemParte findFirstByLivro(String livro);

}
```

So now how I convert the return to one `Ficha`? When I try to use this:

```
Ficha ficha = (Ficha) myRepo.findFirstByLivro("1")
```

returns this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122 cannot be cast
>   to br.com.lumera.cartoriointeligente.entity.Ficha

Comment: Because proxied instance of `FichaSemParte` is *NOT* castable to `Ficha`.

Comment: So how can I return this Ficha with only 2 field to my client? I need to insert field by field in one object to return?

Comment: You do not return `Ficha`, but `FichaSemParte` - which contains only two fields you need. Why do you want to cast it?